# Como adicionar data-slider-bg e .data(slider-bg) para não dar erro no validator w3?

Tags: javascript, html

Ao executar o validador html (https://validator.w3.org) em meu site ele mostra o seguinte erro (Attribute slider-bg not allowed on element article at this point):

programação completa do slider aqui:

https://github.com/devfreelex/sliderdevmean

Como adicionar data-slider-bg e .data(slider-bg) para não erro no validator w3?

Comment: Fala aí, edu! Queira [edit] a sua pergunta e adicionar mais informações sobre o seu problema. Como por exemplo **o erro**.

Comment: Quando executo um verificador html (https://validator.w3.org) ele mostra o erro sobre (slider-bg). Pois o correto seria adicionar entre o <article></article> img src="" mas aí da problema na imagem (tamanho).

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Acontece q o validador identificou um atributo inválido na tag article. Mas, na real, isso não influencia no seu código. O slider faz a leitura desse atributo assim: `var sliderBg = $(this).attr('slider-bg');`. Se, ainda assim, vc se sente incomodado com esse erro, terá de revisar o slider. Isso pode ser facilmente resolvido definindo como data-slider-bg e o slider iria ler com o método .data('slider-bg'). Se algo não está funcionando, com certeza vc esta procurando erro no lugar errado.

Comment: Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Cara, já te dei a faca e o queijo. O que falta pra vc "botar a mão na massa"? Demostre esforço. Sei que vc é capaz! Ou só serve se for código pronto?

Comment: Toma aí, ó: https://github.com/devfreelex/sliderdevmean/pull/1/commits/ffcd9705bd06e7f9beb6885dd4dd9ecdf942f592

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O seu problema é que `slider-bg` não é um [atributo válido](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes). Você pode reverter essa situação trocando todas as referências de "`slider-bg`" por um [`data attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), como por exemplo, "`data-slider-bg`".

Obviamente não vamos refazer o seu código para você. Se o único problema de validação for referente ao atributo inválido, ao trocá-los por `data attributes`, o aviso deve sumir. :)

#### Leitura sugerida:

- [Lista de atributos válidos do HTML 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes);
- [Utilizando data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes);
- [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*).

Comment: Por que o negativo?

Comment: Acho que não vai resolver o problema do colega. **Acho que ele quer pronto**, pois comentei exatamente isso aí na pergunta dele e, ainda assim, fica pedindo ajuda.

Comment: Se quiser, pode utilizar meu *pull request* como referência pra sua resposta: https://github.com/devfreelex/sliderdevmean/pull/1/commits/ffcd9705bd06e7f9beb6885dd4dd9ecdf942f592

Comment: De qualquer modo, o objetivo do site não é criar pull-requests ou dar o **código pronto** como ele pede nesse contexto.

Comment: Entendo perfeitamente. Tanto que não me arrisquei a responder à pergunta. Preferi apontar uma possível solução via comentário. Mesmo assim, é perceptível que o AP não se esforçou em fazer ele mesmo. Nem se quer postou um código próprio para corrigirmos para ele. Se meu objetivo fosse entregar pronto ao AP, teria formulado uma resposta e "referenciado meu pull request". Apesar de que não fiz exclusivamente ao AP, mas sim ao autor do slider. Achei interessante e é "duplamente útil" cooperar corrigindo "parte do código".

Comment: em localhost funciona mas no site (em domínio) não esta aparecendo as imagens...

Comment: Como eu havia comentado: "*Se algo não está funcionando, com certeza vc esta procurando erro no lugar errado*". Não pode soltar uma pergunta aqui sem definir EXPLICITAMENTE qual o seu objetivo, sem passar seu código, apresentar o erro retornado, o que você espera, o que está acontecendo, e etc. Que tal reformular sua pergunta?

Comment: É que antes o slider funcionava perfeitamente, mas o w3c validator acusava aquele erro. Agora o w3c não mostra erro mas as imagens do slider não aparecem... Mas obrigado pela ajuda.